# Interpolation of the value as the property Component

Tags: angular

I have a question about how is the interpolation in the Angular2 done. 
For example, I have the component X, that have value as @Input();
And in the parent component i have such code:

```
<X [value]="{{'hello' | translate}} {{ 'world' | translate }}"></X>
```

But as I can judge such code is wrong. 
I use ng2-translate for internationalization. 
Can you provide me withe the links of information, whick can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you defined an `@Input() some` in the child component, you have 4 options:

1. Do not pass anything - the input will be undefined

`<child-component ...` - expression will be parsed as undefined and `this.some` will be equal to undefined

2. Use neither interpolation nor binding syntax -

`<child-component some="value" ...` - expression will be parsed a string and `this.some` will be equal to `value` string;

3. Use interpolation - `<child-component some="{{value}}"...>`
4. Use binding syntax - `<child-component [some]="value"...>`

Both 3-rd and 4-th option will produce exactly the same [updateBindings function](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce) in the component factory. The expression will be evaluated in the context of the parent component and the input `this.some` will be equal whatever the `value` property of the parent component holds.

Read more in the [Template Syntax manual](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

It seems that in your case the interpolation will do just fine:

```
<X value="{{'hello' | translate}} {{ 'world' | translate }}"></X>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Maximus, appreciate quick and detailed response.

Answer (score 4):

In Angular you **never** use `[]` and '{{}}` together. Either one or the other.

```
<X value="{{'hello' | translate}} {{ 'world' | translate }}"></X>
```

or

```
<X [value]="('hello' | translate) + ' ' + ('world' | translate)"></X>
```