# Can't interpolate variable into object in html

Tags: angular

How can I add a variable to an object in the html? I'm using ngx-countdown timer and I need to add the value of the json data into the [config] object, but I'm having issues figuring out how. How can I interpolate or dynamically insert the value into the config object?

Originally it looked like
`<countdown [config]="{ leftTime: 120, format: 'm:s' }">`

```
Time Left: <countdown [config]="{ leftTime:"+ {{auction.creator.auctionEndDateTime}} + ", format: 'mm:ss' }"></countdown>
</div>
```

Comment: Try [config]="{ leftTime: auction.creator.auctionEndDateTime, format: 'mm:ss' }". [] braces expect input to be a variable or javascript object

Answer (score 1):

Can You try this. you don't need to use interpolation here 
you can write it like this 
     [config]="javascript expression" 
or 
     [config]="'string you want to pass'"
or

```
 <countdown [config]="{ leftTime: auction.creator.auctionEndDateTime, format: 'mm:ss' }"></countdown>
```

for more details you can refer this.

[Interpolation of the value as the property Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535661/interpolation-of-the-value-as-the-property-component)